# Redirect too many in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I'm trying to work on my `.htaccess` file

What I want to do is to redirect all request to https://example.com/

Means all request for different pages of the domain should be redirect to the homepage/landing page for now.

I tried to do this in `.htaccess`

`Redirect 301 / https://example.com/`

But this gives me an output like this

`redirect too many times`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like your are also redirecting requests to `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/`, right? ;-)

You need to take care that you only apply your redirection rule if the incoming request does not already request exactly that URL you are trying to redirect to. Two approaches here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Or just:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?.+ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).